# No such Directory Error >

Tags: iphone, ios4, iphone-sdk-3.0

i am using in my code this protocol:

```
#import "AdMobDelegateProtocol.h"
```

but i am facing no such file or directory found ??

help needed.

Comment: Additional information: You run into this problem if you download Google's AdMob SDK (which does not contain the named file) and try to use it in Google's AdWhirl mediation scheme (which does not contain the file.)  There are copies of the file in code.google.com... as part of other packages, but I have no way to know what's current, what version goes with what SDK, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Pls check if the file is present in the project folder or tree in the correct destination. This indicates that there is no such file or is missing in the specified folder/destination

Comment: no file in not in projct .. but i thnk its a iphone builtin file ? m i rite ?

Answer (score 0):

This error shows AdMobDelegateProtocol.h not present in your app bundle. either it need any kind of reference if you use this from any code present at net or you missing to include any framework or it also may possible you create any kind of typo. not more than this

Comment: #import "AdWhirlAdNetworkAdapter.h"
#import "AdMobDelegateProtocol.h"

@class AdMobView;

@interface AdWhirlAdapterAdMob : AdWhirlAdNetworkAdapter <AdMobDelegate> {

}

+ (AdWhirlAdNetworkType)networkType;

@end i am using this

Comment: please check your resources you have any file named AdMobDelegateProtocol.h.

Answer (score 0):

From your comments I see you use AdWhirl.

If you want to use AdMob with AdWhirl you have to add the AdMob framework to your project.
There are no Ad frameworks included in AdWhirl. You have to add them to your project. AdWhirl just uses them, but you have to add them.

You can find the AdMob SDK and install instructions on the admob website.

Comment: Please see my comment under the original question.  The file is not part of the AdMob SDK, yet the AdWhirl SDK requires it.